# Can't connect PC to Mac (Xamarin.iOS versions mismatch)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-mac

I'm trying to connect my Windows 10 to my Mac to build a Xamarin.Forms app as I've done in the past. However, I'm getting the following error:

> Xamarin.iOS versions mismatch The Xamarin.iOS SDK version installed on
>   Mac is not compatible with this version of Visual Studio. Would you
>   like us to install Xamarin.iOS '11.14' for you? This will overwrite
>   any existing Xamarin.iOS installation on your Mac.

Indeed, the version on the Mac is 11.12.0.4. I'm on the stable channel, and it's telling me there are no updates. and I'm on the latest VS on my PC - 15.8.1.

I tried clicking 'Install' but it fails telling me that

> There were problems installing...

Is there a way to solve this *without* uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio (which might not even help)?

Comment: Have you tried opening Visual Studio on the Mac and under the menu bar 'Visual Studio' -> 'Check for Updates...' and seeing what it shows?

Comment: In fact I only see 11.14 in the Beta channel for updates for Mac Visual Studio, you may either need to rollback or switch to the Beta channel and update manually

Comment: @Bijington I'm using VS2107, latest build. As I wrote in the question. I've found the "answer" though, and posted it below.

Comment: apologies I got my versions mixed up thinking 15.X meant VS 2015

Comment: @Bijington No problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further searching the only solution at the moment seems to be to use the beta channel in order to install Xamarin.iOS 11.14 on the Mac.

However, the better solution seems to be to wait. It's supposed to be updated

> really soon [Yes. That's a quote.]

Sources for all of that (and how to upgrade using the beta channel):

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/4623

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/311561/installing-xamarinios-1114-from-the-vs4win-connect.html

**EDIT**

[Visual Studio for Mac has been updated.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-mac-relnotes#release-history) We're supposed to be able to update it and it's supposed to work now.

Comment: Haha I literally just made the same discovery

Comment: @Bijington Yes. And I rather wait a couple of days rather then install the beta, only to have to uninstall it later if they change it and it's incompatible... I'm SO glad I didn't uninstall and reinstall as other posts suggest.